# what's the difference between app-id and app-key on most open platform?

Tags: security, oauth, oauth-2.0

In most open platform system, like Facebook, Twitter.

There are three value for client application.
**App-Id**,**App-Key**,**App-Secret**.

**App-Secret** is easy to understand. a secret value never show to public, must not be bundled into client application for security.

**App-Id**,**App-Key** both are used to distinguish client application with others. Both maybe bundled into client application.

I think that App-Id/App-Secret pair, or App-Key/App-Secret pair works well for most situation.

Why most platform needs both App-Id and App-Key?
What's the design purpose?

Now, I think both App-Id and App-Key are just a ID,
App-Id is a number id, App-Key is a UUID. is it right?

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR - the definition of terms "App Id" and "App Key" depends on the service provider's implementation of an authorization strategy. Often the "App Id" will mean oAuth client id and "App Key" will mean oAuth client secret but some providers may define "App Id" and "App Key" to mean the same thing (client id).

Full story:

The terms are based on oAuth protocol. (OpenID Connect used by some platforms is a superset of oAuth). As you might know, in oAuth there are 3 entities that collaborate: the *client*, *authorization server* and *resource server.* The client represents the client app being authorized. In order for the authorization server to distinguish between clients (app A vs app B), the client must register with authorization server. From [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) (oAuth 2.0):

> Before initiating the protocol, the client registers with the
> authorization server.  The means through which the client registers
> with the authorization server are beyond the scope of this
> specification but typically involve end-user interaction with an HTML
> registration form.

When the client registers, it receives a *client id:*

> The authorization server issues the registered client a clien
> identifier -- a unique string representing the registration
> information provided by the client.  The client identifier is not a
> secret; it is exposed to the resource owner and MUST NOT be used alone
> for client authentication.  The client identifier is unique to the
> authorization server.

Furthermore, if the client type is *confidential* (defined by the spec as *capable of maintaining the confidentiality of their credentials or capable of secure client authentication using other means*), the spec requires the client to establish a way to authenticate itself:

> The client and authorization server establish a client authentication
> method suitable for the security requirements of the authorization
> server.  The authorization server MAY accept any form of client
> authentication meeting its security requirements. Confidential clients
> are typically issued (or establish) a set of client credentials used
> for authenticating with the authorization server (e.g., password,
> public/private key pair).

So far we have two things - the client id and an optional set of client credentials. In many flows (grant types), the latter does become a single item known as a *client secret*, essentially a password.

Some platforms may refer to client id as 'app key', others call it 'consumer id', yet others call it 'client key'. Twitter created this [pithy doc note](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/3-legged-oauth) in an attempt to dispel the confusion:

> **Client Credentials:**
>
> App Key === API Key === Consumer API Key === Consumer Key === Customer Key === oauth_consumer_key
>
> App Key Secret === API Secret Key === Consumer Secret === Consumer Key
> === Customer Key

This note is terribly unhelpful. They're trying to illustrate a point that implementations across the universe assign different labels to the same concept but their attempt is a poor one. Twitter's implementation does not use an App Key Secret, they only need an App Key (client id). In Twitter's flows the App Key/client id is referred to as `oauth_consumer_key`.

If you take a look at docs of other service providers, you'll get a better idea. Facebook wraps a lot of oAuth flows in their own APIs so they're not a good example. [Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_terminology.htm&type=5) is a more straightforward implementation. It calls client id a Consumer Key and client secret a Consumer Secret.

In summary, the requirement of supplying a client id and an optional client secret is driven by the oAuth specification. If the service provider complies with oAuth, the labels they use for their own implementation should correspond to the spec. And Twitter should use more than 140 characters in their documentation!

Comment: **App-ID/App-Secret** is enough, and easy to be understand.
**App-Key** is confusable, from literal meaning, it may be a ID or a secret.
Here need standard.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare it with our Basic Authentication then it will make it easy to understand. Like **App ID/Client ID** is like your Username/Email and **App Secret/Client Secret** is like Password.

So in **OAuth2** when making a request for Authorization Code then you need to send **App ID** to uniquely identify your app.  After that, you are requested to send your App secret to get the Token.